# How to develop a PDF viewer without using third party libraries in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a PDF viewer in android.I dont want to use any 3rd party libraries like PDFBox,iText...Is it possible in android?

Comment: Theoretically, everything's possible. Practically, you'll need some help from Adobe or at least the source code of some open source PDF viewer project, and it's still gonna take some months (assuming you have at least 20-30 people on your team).

Answer (score 2):

Start by getting a copy of the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf.html), then implement it.